# How to root Xperia Z Ultra safely?

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia, sony-xperia-z

I want to root my Xperia Z ultra . but not finding any safe method for it. I have heard of kingroot . is that safe ? please help me to find other safe ways to root my device.

Answer (score 0):

According to [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2453947), you can root the Xperia Z Ultra by using [V root](http://root.mgyun.com/)

> **1)** Enable USB debugging [/Settings/Developer options] 
>   - To enable Developer options you need to go on /Settings/About phone/ and tap your 'Build number' 8 times...
>   **2)** Download your device drivers, then install them.... and then 
>   **3)** Download VRoot (http://www.mgyun.com/vroot)
>   **4)** Install VRoot
>   **5)** Your phone needs to be turned on and your lock screen unlocked... 
>   **6)** Click the green button on the far right of the vRoot application.
>   **7)** Now, your phone will restart by itself. (repeat the steps again if this does not work)
>   **8)** Unplug your phone from the USB, and check to see if the chinese version of superSU is installed. (it will look like a blue shield)
>   **9)** Then go to the playstore, and download superSU/ superuser. Open superSU/ superuser. 
>   **10)** Allow binary update, and then plug your device back into your laptop, and open vRoot.
>   **11)** Click the white button (unroot) and wait for your device to reboot
>   **12)** Click on superSU/ superuser (which ever you downloaded) and allow binary update (again!), then go into the superSU/ superuser settings > and select 'install to system'
>   **13)** restart your device.... done!

Comment: can you please suggest any other method which does not use software installment other than Super su?

Comment: I would also add that kingroot does not meet the "safely" requirement.

Comment: FYI, the link for "V root" is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download KingRoot for your device and it is safe I'm using it from last 4 years
Download from
https://kingroot.net/

**It have following features**

1. Root Defence-consist of url as well as device security
2. Game Booster
3. Purify-Auto clean phone cache to save power
4. Uninstaller tool
5. Accelerate Charging

**NOTE :** You have to connect your phone with internet(It need approx 2MB)

**Installing Process**
Open KingRoot

it will check whether phone is  rooted or not.

then click try root button to start rooting

Now wait for the 100% process ,after this your phone is rooted

Hope it will solve your problem...

Comment: Kingroot doesn't works on all mobile phones.

Comment: FYI, the link for "KingRoot" is dead.